# Error compiling kernel Galaxy Note3

Tags: android, linux-kernel

I'm getting the following error when trying to compile the kernel of Note3.
This is a kernel from Samsung.
Does someone has any suggestion how to fix it?

```
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ran/android/system/kernel/samsung/ha3g'
    make  -C kernel/samsung/ha3g O=/home/ran/android/system/out/target/product/ha3g/obj/KERNEL_OBJ ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=" /home/ran/android/system/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.7/bin/arm-eabi-" headers_install
    make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ran/android/system/kernel/samsung/ha3g'
      CHK     include/linux/version.h
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ran/android/system/kernel/samsung/ha3g'
    make  -C kernel/samsung/ha3g O=/home/ran/android/system/out/target/product/ha3g/obj/KERNEL_OBJ ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=" /home/ran/android/system/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.7/bin/arm-eabi-" zImage
    make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ran/android/system/kernel/samsung/ha3g'
      GEN     /home/ran/android/system/out/target/product/ha3g/obj/KERNEL_OBJ/Makefile
    scripts/kconfig/conf --silentoldconfig Kconfig
      Using /home/ran/android/system/kernel/samsung/ha3g as source for kernel
      GEN     /home/ran/android/system/out/target/product/ha3g/obj/KERNEL_OBJ/Makefile
      CHK     include/linux/version.h
      CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
    make[3]: `include/generated/mach-types.h' is up to date.
      CALL    /home/ran/android/system/kernel/samsung/ha3g/scripts/checksyscalls.sh
      CHK     include/generated/compile.h
      CC      drivers/sensorhub/stm/factory/light_max88921.o
    /home/ran/android/system/kernel/samsung/ha3g/drivers/sensorhub/stm/factory/light_max88921.c:78:1: fatal error: opening dependency file drivers/sensorhub/stm/factory/.light_max88921.o.d: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    make[5]: *** [drivers/sensorhub/stm/factory/light_max88921.o] Error 1
    make[4]: *** [drivers/sensorhub/stm] Error 2
    make[3]: *** [drivers/sensorhub] Error 2
    make[2]: *** [drivers] Error 2
    make[1]: *** [sub-make] Error 2
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ran/android/system/kernel/samsung/ha3g'
    make: *** [TARGET_KERNEL_BINARIES] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Somehow the folder factory was missing under out/target/product/ha3g/obj/KERNEL_OBJ/drivers/sensorhub/stm
When I added this folder (with mkdir) it worked.